# Is it possible to change value for bat file using nsis script?

Tags: nsis

I have successfully build the nsi script using nsis plugin in my eclipse.I have bat file in my project.I have JVM_DLL,HOME_PATH two variables with default value in that bat file.I have created a Textbox and gave as default value for that JVM_DLL and HOME_PATH.If i change in text box value that should be reflected in batch file.I have tried following codes

```
 ${ConfigWrite} "$INSTDIR\batch.bat" "JVM_DLL" "=$JVM_DLL" $R0
 ${configWrite} "$INTDIR\batch.bat" "HOME_PATH" "=$HOME_PATH" $R1
```

but the changed value is not reflected in batch file.How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the [NSIS docs](http://anders_k.users.sourceforge.net/public/NSIS/2.46/Manual.html#configwrite) again you will see in the batch file example that the syntax is `"SET name=" "newvalue"` and not `"name" "=newvalue"`. You could also check $R0 and $R1, they will report which operation was performed...